# VirtualBox icon not showing on launcher. Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Tags: virtualbox, icons, launcher, virtualization, .desktop

I googled it and asked ChatGPT but can't solve this.

The issue that I'm trying to fix is that I can't see the virtual machine icon when a VM is running. The VirtualBox icon is working, but the launcher icon of the VM is blank. When I pass the mouse over it, it blinks but there are no "image" there.

It worked when I opened the VM for the first time, but failed suddenly and never appeared again.

[image]